# About pthread_create() and pthread_join()

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pointers, pthreads

I just started to study `pthread` for cross-platform. But I'm really confused about variable types used for `pthread_create()` and `pthread_join()`. Please look at the following code.

```
// This is just simple code for test, so don't take this variable seriously!
int result;
void* myThreadFunc(void* arg) {
    result = *(int*)arg;

    // Why not &result, but result???
    return (void*)result;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t myThread;
    int argForThread = 10;
    int threadResult = 0;

    pthread_create(&myThread, NULL, myThreadFunc, (void*)&argForThread);

    // Why (void**), but not (void*)?
    pthread_join(myThread, (void**)&threadResult);

    return 0;
}
```

As I wrote in the comments, I don't understand about those pointers, it doesn't make sense to me.

**For the first one, why do I have to put value type one for pointer type?**

**For the second one, why do I need double pointer casting for just an address of a local variable?**

Comment: One question at a time please.

Comment: But I think it's one question in the end, this question is all about POINTER in C++. Not about functions actually.

Comment: You want cross-platform code? Use C++' `std::thread`!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks for the information. It would be very helpful someday, but this time, I should stick to C :)

Comment: Your question is tagged with C++! That's a different language and you should not have used is as a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `myThreadFunc` takes as its argument a pointer to any location in memory. We don't know the type of that location, so it's a `void *` and you cast it to whatever type you want. You cast it to a pointer to the integer `argForThread`, which would be `&argForThread` and then you derefrence it, producing the value of 10.

Your return statement is incorrect. You are returning `&result` but the variable is on the stack. Once the function returns, the variable no longer exists.  If you want to return a computed value to the caller, you would need to allocate memory for that and then return the address of the allocated memory. The caller would then derefrence the address that it receives, get the value, and the finally free the memory.  (Novice programmers might return the address of a static value or something on the stack, but that would not be threadsafe.)

When you return `(void *)result`, you are returning the value `result` as if it were a pointer to somewhere in memory. That memory location is almost certainly invalid. However, it doesn't matter, because you don't dereference the location returned. (I should note that you will get unpredictable behavior on a system that has 32-bit integers and 64-bit pointers.)

The thread result is a `void **` because you are passing in a pointer that will be mutated to point to the location returned by `myThreadFunc`. So in your example, `threadResult` will end up with the value `result * result`, so it will be pointing to the invalid memory location.  That's okay in your example, because `threadResult` is an integer, not a pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your kind explanation and pointing out my mistake on the return statement, I edited now. But still don't understand why I can't put just `(void*)&result` but `(void*)result`. `void*` is pointer type, and `result` is just a value itself.

Comment: `result` is a stack variable that ceases to exist when the function returns. If you return `&result`, you are returning a pointer to a location in memory that will probably be very different very soon.

Comment: You want to return the *value* of `result`, not its meaningless address on a stack that's about to cease to exist.

Comment: I edited so the variable `result` is a global variable. What I mean is `int a = 123; void* pa = (void*)a;` doesn't make sense because both types are different. But `int a = 123; void* pa = (void*)&a;` makes sense.

Comment: If you want to return `(void *)&a`, that's fine, but you then need to pass to `pthread_join` the address of a pointer, and you need to dereference that to get your value.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers